# Django inheriting from base.html not displaying content on child page

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a `base.html` file:

```
 {% load static %}
{% load custom_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        {% comment %} <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dashboardscript.js' %}" defer></script> {% endcomment %}
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script> 
        <title>Codera | Dashboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      
        {% block nav %}
        <div class="nav-container">
         <img src="{% static 'levelstatic/assets/coderalogo.svg' %}" style="margin: 0 auto;
         width: 80%; margin-bottom: 25px;" alt="CODERA">
             <div class="nav-links">
                 <div class="nav-link nav-active">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/learn.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>LEARN</a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="nav-link">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/review.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>REVIEW</a>
                 </div> 
                 <div class="nav-link">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/progress.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>PROGRESS</a>
                 </div> 
                 <div class="nav-link">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/compete.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>COMPETE</a>
                 </div> 
             </div>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}

    </body>
        
</html>
```

And I inherit from the `base.html` file on my `dashboard.html` file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

However, the `<h1>` does not show up and instead all that is displayed is the content from the `base.html`. Could someone possibly help me with this? Why is the `<h1>` not displaying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the `{% block content %}` in your base HTML file. When Django inherits from the base HTML file it searches for all of the blocks you have provided in the parent template and replaces them with the ones you have provided in the child template. So if you provide a `block` in the child template where it does not exist in the parent template it would do nothing. If you want to tell Django to include the `h1` tag in the `content` block you have to place the `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` in the parent template so Django knows where to replace it.

For example you can put `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` like this:

```html
{% load static %}
{% load custom_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        {% comment %} <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dashboardscript.js' %}" defer></script> {% endcomment %}
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script> 
        <title>Codera | Dashboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      
        {% block nav %}
        <div class="nav-container">
         <img src="{% static 'levelstatic/assets/coderalogo.svg' %}" style="margin: 0 auto;
         width: 80%; margin-bottom: 25px;" alt="CODERA">
             <div class="nav-links">
                 <div class="nav-link nav-active">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/learn.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>LEARN</a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="nav-link">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/review.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>REVIEW</a>
                 </div> 
                 <div class="nav-link">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/progress.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>PROGRESS</a>
                 </div> 
                 <div class="nav-link">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/compete.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>COMPETE</a>
                 </div> 
             </div>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

    </body>
        
</html>
```

So when you add the code below

```html
{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

to the child template, django will replace it with the content block in the parent.